# How to put a php variable in a javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have a script as follows -

```
<script>
//alert(window.screen.width);
if (window.screen.width < 250) {
// resolution is below 10 x 25
//alert(window.screen.width);
window.location = 'http://m.xyz.com/'; 
}
</script>
```

I have a variable in a php file as follows -

```
 define("url",     "xyz.com", true);
```

My question is how can I put the url as a variable in the javascript

I tried the following but it does not work and says "site cannot be reached"

```
  <script>
//alert(window.screen.width);
if (window.screen.width < 250) {
// resolution is below 10 x 25
//alert(window.screen.width);
window.location = 'http://m.<?php echo $url ?>'; 
}
</script>
```

Comment: 1. are you sure that the define statement is included in your file. 2. is the url valid. 3. the $url needs to be replaced with url (defined value not a variable).

Comment: @jeff 1. Yes, the define statement is included in a separate php file and the php file is included in the file 2. 2. Yes, url is valid 3. If I replace $url with url, it does not work

Comment: It does not work is not a useful comment. What does/doesn't happen? What does the console tell you?

Comment: It redirects to a site with address m.url meaning it does not get the value

Comment: this code is ok i have tested it, check if condition will true or false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please write like this into your PHP file, I tried below code and it is working fine for me:

```
<?php define("url","xyz.com", true); ?>


 <script>
 //alert(window.screen.width);
 if (window.screen.width < 250) {
 // resolution is below 10 x 25
 //alert(window.screen.width);
 window.location = 'http://m.<?php echo url ?>'; 
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks @Ajay Malhotra

Answer (score 0):

Just replace:

```
<?php echo $url ?>
```

by:

```
<?= $url ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Constants don't need to use $ so just use like

```
   <?=url?>
```

it will work